# Cropping children based on parent's border-radius

Tags: html, css, crop, border-radius

In the example snippet below, I try to impose on the last child of the `.container` element the same `border-radius` as `.container`, so that when that last child gets highlighted upon hovering, its background follows the shape of the parent. This *seems to* work pretty well in this specific case where I've set `border-radius` in terms of pixels.

```css
.container {
  display: block;
  width: 10em;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  border-radius: 0 0 20px 0;
  box-shadow: 0.1em 0.1em 0.4em black;
}

.entry:hover {
  background-color: #aaa;
}

.entry:last-child {
  border-radius: inherit;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="entry">
  First
  </div>
  <div class="entry">
  second
  </div>
  <div class="entry">
  third
  </div>
</div>
```

However, if I use `em`s, e.g. `2em` instead of `20px`, things break like this:

[image]

I guess this is because the curvature of the parent extends higher than the height of the last child. Indeed if I change `20px` to `50px` I get this:

[image]

Therefore, I think that with `20px` I'm just lucky, and that the overall approach of inheriting `border-radius` in an attempt to have children follow the shape of the parent is wrong. Indeed, in the last example of `50px`, the *second* entry would have to be cropped in away that is simply not obtainable via `border-radius`.

How can I go about it instead?

Comment: Mhmm, works perfectly fine for me

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### Answer:

Use this css
`overflow: hidden`

#### Correct code for OP's question:

```css
.container {
  display: block;
  width: 10em;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  border-radius: 0 0 2em 0;
  box-shadow: 0.1em 0.1em 0.4em black;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.entry:hover {
  background-color: #aaa;
}

.entry:last-child {
  border-radius: inherit;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="entry">
  First
  </div>
  <div class="entry">
  second
  </div>
  <div class="entry">
  third
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This seems to work fine, and no need to set the last child's border radius.

Comment: In hindsight it's trivial... and I'm already using the `overflow: hidden;` setting somewhere else on the page, but... wow, it's not easy to think at the appropriate tool when solving a problem. Thanks!!